# Is there any way to fetch only city and country from user input on googleplacesautocomplete api using react?

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

I can not get only city and country as an output from googleautocomplete component using react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this would be to specify the `types` parameter on the Google Places Autocomplete component.  However, the limitation there is that you can only really specify one of the options for types:

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a
>   certain type by passing a types parameter. The parameter specifies a
>   type or a type collection, as listed in the supported types below. If
>   nothing is specified, all types are returned. In general only a single
>   type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode
>   and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect
>   as specifying no types.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types

So the best option for your situation would probably be to use the `(regions)` type collection, but this will include more than just cities and countries such as neighborhoods.  Another option would be to use the `(cities)` type collection which will include only cities.

I also highly recommend the [react-geosuggest](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) library if you want something pre-made to accomplish this as you can pass those as parameters and style it yourself.

```
<Geosuggest
  types={['(regions)']}
/>
```

**EDIT**

I think I might have misunderstood the question a bit.  If you're trying to figure out how to get the street address, city, and country out of the response you get from the Places API, you're going to have to submit an additional request.

Once the user selects the place from the list, you will have to get the `place_id` out of the original request and submit a [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request. One of the fields in the response will be `address_component` which has [this very strange format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types). I posted an example of what this full format looks like [here](https://gist.github.com/csandman/ee9ee7434d824e361682e28b4f59dbcb).

I made a simple converter function that will return the basic components of an address in a manageable format:

```js
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// returns:

// {
//   address_1
//   address_2
//   city
//   state_code
//   zip_code
//   country
// }

function convertAddressComponents(addrComp) {
  let newAddr = {};
  let address_1 = [];
  addrComp.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el.types.includes("post_box")) {
      address_1.push(el.long_name);
    } else if (el.types.includes("street_number")) {
      address_1.push(el.long_name);
    } else if (el.types.includes("route")) {
      address_1.push(el.long_name);
    } else if (el.types.includes("subpremise")) {
      newAddr.address_2 = el.long_name;
    } else if (el.types.includes("locality")) {
      newAddr.city = el.long_name;
    } else if (el.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")) {
      newAddr.state_code = el.short_name;
    } else if (el.types.includes("postal_code")) {
      newAddr.zip_code = el.short_name;
    } else if (el.types.includes("country")) {
      newAddr.country = el.long_name;
    }
  });
  newAddr.address_1 = address_1.join(" ");

  return newAddr;
}
```

Feel free to modify this to suite your needs.

Comment: Thank you, Chris! I kind got what I need isolating the terms by index from the output... for now it will do but since different countries have different address formats, I am not able to return just the types I want yet... l am, for instance, I did not find a way that from the user input I am able to always return street_address, city, country...

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood your original question, I updated my answer to hopefully better answer you.  Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes. It helps, @ChrisSandvik. Thanks. Your thinking is perfect but the google api that I am using doens't give me the output that I am looking for yet...

Comment: Which are you using specifically?  Are you using a react component?  It would help if I could see an example of the code you're trying to use

Comment: I decided to reduce my goals and put a hard code with all the info that I need for all the countries and use name, latitude and longitude to match them with the data coming from the GoogleMapReact.